# Unable to import CSS file in the React JSX component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

`./src/App.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/App.css) BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query` and_qq undefined`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query. at Array.reduce (<anonymous>) at Array.some (<anonymous>) at Array.filter (<anonymous>)`

this is the error I'm getting when trying to import CSS files in the JSX component.

[file structue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpfRZ.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M8eN.png): [component file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M8eN.png)

Comment: Share you folder structure please

Answer (score 0):

I updated the css-loader module and it solved the problem.

The css-loader was using older browserslist module i guess.